# Using data received from Axios Post request response

Tags: reactjs, axios

Can someone pls give me some advice?

I need to create a report of all messages I sent via rest API.
I got my rest api post request working. What i need now is to extract some data from the Response and use it outside the Axios request. Ideally in another component. Context API doesn't work.
Data can be grouped into object i called stats.

Thats my axios request:

```
axios.post(url, glbody, {headers:headers})
  .then((response) => {
    const stats ={    
  id: response.data.messages[0].dateTime, 
  date: response.data.messages[0].dateTime,
  from: response.data.messages[0].origin,
  to: response.data.messages[0].destination,
  status: response.data.messages[0].status,
  } 
 
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: i would typically save your stats object in a state and pass it down to the desired component. Also could you clarify why context wouldnt work?

Comment: how can i wrap context provider around the function? in examples i looked at they always wrap around components. I need to wrap around function: